# Remove word from url with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I want to remove 2 words from wordpress urls with htaccess:
So i have:

```
https://website.co/product-category/cat/cat2/ and 
https://website.co/product/cat/cat2/product-name
```

I want to remove "product-category" from the first link and "product" from the second link.
This is what i tried but didn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^product-category$ / [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The first rule should have worked to remove "product" from the second URL?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this redirect rule for both redirects:

```
RewriteRule ^product(?:-category)?/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

`product(?:-category)?` matches `product` or `product-category`.

Comment: @RoX: Did this work out?